# Defining required fields via a dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I add / remove required attribute from the textfields depending on a < select > option?

Example: if option 3 is selectd make all fields `required`. Else make only `field1` & `fieldX` required?

html

```
<form id=section3Form>
     <input type="text" id="field1">
     <input type="text" id="field2">
     <input type="text" id="field3">
     <input type="text" id="field4">
     <select id="fieldP" required>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 1</option>
     </select>

     <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" value"Submit">
</form>
```

jQ:

```
$(#submitBtn).click(function(){
  if ($('#fieldP').val() == "option3") {
      //all fields are required
} else {
     //field1` & `fieldX are required.
}
});
```

Comment: what if option 2 is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you're trying to achieve, you can use the following code to make it a little more more dynamic regarding your JavaScript. Just add to each options data-required attribute the inputs that are required (as a comma separated list) and it will work:

**HTML**

```
<form id="section3Form">

     <input type="text" id="field1">

     <input type="text" id="field2">

     <input type="text" id="field3">

     <input type="text" id="field4">

     <select id="fieldP" required>

        <option value="option1" data-required="field1,field2">Option 1</option>

        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>

        <option value="option3" data-required="field3">Option 3</option>

     </select>

     <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value"Submit">

</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){

    $("#submitBtn").click(function(e){

        var selected = $('#fieldP option:selected');

        var required = selected.attr('data-required') ? selected.attr('data-required').split(",") : undefined;

        if(required) {

            $.each(required, function(index, value) {

                alert("Input = " + value + " is Required" );

            });
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question this may use for you:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#fieldP').change(function(){
             if($('#fieldP').val() == "option3")              
             {
                 $("input[id^='field']").attr('required','required');
             } 
             else
             {
                 $("#field1").attr('required','required');
                 // same for fieldx
                 // to remove required attribute
                 //$("#field1").removeAttr('required');
             }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function....

```
function bindRequired(select, value, fieldsId, invert){

    var fields = fieldsId.map(function(id){
        return document.querySelector(id);
    }).filter(function(el){
        return !!el;
    });

    function changeEvent(){



        var isRequired =  select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == value;

        if(invert) isRequired = !isRequired;

        var method = isRequired ? "setAttribute" : "removeAttribute";
        fields.forEach(function(field){

                field[method]("required", isRequired);        
        });

    }

    select.addEventListener("change", changeEvent);  

    changeEvent();

}

bindRequired(document.querySelector("#fieldP"), "option2", ["#field1", "#field3"]);
bindRequired(document.querySelector("#fieldP"), "option3", ["#field1", "#field2", "#field3", "#field4"]);
```

see working in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h3jum8sf/